# How rollback all inserted record in an iteration in a loop

Tags: exception, db2, procedure

I want to insert a bunch of record in DB2 by a procedure and when an exception raises I want rollback all other insert before this insert and  iterate loop for the next cursor record

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIBA_ICMS2 (in IN_BRANCH_NO integer)
    LANGUAGE SQL
MAIN_BLOCK:
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_ID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;
begin
insert into t1 --rollback this one when in the next on an exception occur
insert into t2
  --an exception occur
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [SAVEPOINT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003271.html) statement.
I can’t provide an exact code example since I don’t see any loops / cursors in your code snippet.